# 'protect_from_forgery' in Application controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

In the `config/application_controller.rb` file in my Rails application directory, I found the code below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

Can any one tell me what `project_from_forgery` means and why it is being used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It protects from csrf. e.g. all POST requests should have specific security token.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Answer (score 2):

This is rails built in feature to prevent csrf attacks,

Learn more from this link,

http://railskey.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/rails-protect_from_forgery/

Cross site scripting attack is prevented by adding the authentication token to form field as hidden field. On Post request that token is matched against the one stored in database.

Comment: It's against CSRF. XSS is different type of attacks.

Answer (score -1):

**`protect_from_forgery`**: A feature in Rails that protects against Cross-site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks.

This feature makes all generated forms have a hidden `id` field. This `id` field must match the stored `id` or the form submission is not accepted.

This prevents malicious forms on other sites or forms inserted with XSS from submitting to the Rails application.